# Matplotlib scatter plot with pie as marker

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization

I am strictly following the official tutorial for how to make a scatter plot, but the marker will be a pie chart instead of a dot. (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_piecharts.html) But what I found weird is the arc we specified as marker is not exactly as what I expected, let me clarify:

```
r1 = 0.1
size = 60
x1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0,r1))
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0,r1))
xy1 = np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x1, y1])])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([0.5], [0.5], marker=xy1, s=size**2, facecolor='blue')
```

Although the arc may look decent at first glance, if you zoom in, you will find the issue:

[image]

If I change the marker path a bit, the issue become clearer:

```
r1 = 0.1
size = 60
x1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0,r1))
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0,r1))
xy1 = np.row_stack([[0.5, 0.5], np.column_stack([x1, y1])])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([0.5], [0.5], marker=xy1, s=size**2, facecolor='blue')
```

the arc looks like below, same issue:

[image]

I am using matplotlib 3.5.2 for this example, can anyone offer some hints here?

Comment: What is the version of your matplotlib? Can you try to increase the size by `size = 6000`, and also try increase the resolution of scatter by `np.linspace(0, r1, 10000)`? I can generate a standard pie chart with this code.

Comment: @ChangYe, thanks a lot for the response, I am using 3.5.2 and I just updated the question to better clarify my point. Yes, increasing `size` will alleviate the visual effect of this problem but doesn't eliminate it, and indeed I can get a decent pie chart as well, but the issue become obvious when zooming in

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually because of the `edge`, this issue can be resolved by setting `lw=0`.

```
r1 = 0.1
size = 60
x1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0,r1))
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.linspace(0,r1))
xy1 = np.row_stack([[0, 0], np.column_stack([x1, y1])])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([0.5], [0.5], marker=xy1, s=size**2, facecolor='blue',edgecolor='red',lw=0)
```